# Macbook Pro stuck after I enter my password

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, password

For last 2 days I am not able to login to my MacBook Pro. It was working fine and suddenly for no reason after I last shutdown my mac I am not able to login.
The mac starts up fine and goes to the login screen. After I enter my password the progress bar is stuck in 70%-80% and sometimes at 100%.

I tried resetting NVRAM and SCM but it didn't help.
I also tried following the steps mentioned in [Justin Silver’s blog post](https://www.justinsilver.com/technology/os-x-el-capitan-10-11-1-hanging-on-boot-fixed/) but it also didn't help.

As mentioned in the post, I moved all the 3rd Party items from `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/Extensions` to `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/ExtensionsDisabled`. Since I was not able to find any *.kext in `/System/Library/Extensions` older than 2016, I didn't moved any *.kext from `/System/Library/Extensions` location.

My MBP is mid 2012 and have the latest OS X, also I have 1TB HDD and 8GB RAM.

I am not able to login using SafeMode as FileVault is enabled. I even tried login in Single User or Verbose mode but I am not able to do so.

Can anyone help me to fix this.

Comment: A even simplistic solution. Purposely put the wrong password in until it asks you if you want to reset the password using your Apple ID. Say yes and then it will reboot into the screen where you can change your password. Leave everything blank (no password) and then when it boots up proceed to login normal but now without password. And boom problem solved.

Answer (score 22):

I found a solution for this problem by [robertk1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7376445?tstart=0) and he writes the following:

> I would enter my password correctly and then the cursor would change to the spinning pinwheel and just sit there forever. The only way out was a power off reboot.

This is exactly what happend with my machine and it looks like it's same with yours. I hope this also works with FileVault enabled. There are two ways to solve this. With and without a *guest account*.

In case you **do** have access to the *guest account* follow these steps by [hijoncon](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7376445?answerId=7376445021#7376445021):

> 1. Login as guest
> 2. Open Terminal (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> then search *terminal*)
> 3. Enter `su your_account`
> 4. Enter your password
> 5. `sudo find /private/var/folders | grep com.apple.LaunchServices | grep csstore`
> 6. Remove every `.csstore` your find like this `sudo rm /private/var/folders/cd/someLongRandomNameHere/someFolderNumberHere/com.apple.LaunchService-whatever.csstore`

If you **don't** have access to the *guest account* you can try different ways to get into the machine (like SSH) [robertk1 suggests](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7376445?tstart=0):

> To do this, you'll either need to be in a recovery console, or ssh
>   into the machine, or boot from an external drive, or otherwise somehow
>   get to a command prompt.

Once you are in the machine you can delete the files like described above in the last steps.

Comment: **Holy smokes** I can't even express how much **_gold_** this information is! I spent a lot of time rotating between reboots, safe-boots, hard resets, "soft" resets by triggering the reboot dialog... and this thing solved it in 2 minutes. :O

Comment: This is a *gold pearl*! In my case, as reported by *robertk1* in the link reported by adriaan, the issue was also caused by Launch System Daemon. It was "stucked by those cache files". So, deleting them fixed the issue. Thanks @adriaan!

Comment: You are a hero!

Answer (score 4):

I know this might not be an option for you is not really a solution... But what I did is to reinstall the OS by entering into Recovery Mode with Command + R right after pressing the power button, same as you would do with safe mode.

I didn't lose my files by doing so, but it took 3 hours more or less for the installation to be completed. Let me know if you found another way.

Comment: i did the same, but the problem still occured T_T)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Fill the password as usual, but don't hit enter yet. Hold the options button and then click the login arrow button.

I've been stuck for a while now, finally this solved, a method in which I introduced the options button. Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't hit the return key!! HIT THE ARROW KEY ON THE RIGHT SIDE TO LOGIN AFTER FILLING PASSWORD. The second time I restarted, the same issue. The thing is, I was using the return key to commit the password but here it seems if you hit the arrow key on the right, logs in just fine.

Comment: I will confirm @Hapots comment.  This was super weird after getting a Mac mini and running a eGPU and enabling FileVault and rebooting to this puzzle.  Arrow via onboard HDMI to another monitor was the trick.  Enter a dead end.  And no onboard HDMI monitor a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

You can still log into Safe Mode, even with File Vault enabled, and that’s exactly what I’d try next if I was you.

The only difference is that you’ll probably be asked to log in twice: once to unlock the startup disk, and again to log in to the Finder.

Full instructions below:

1. Fully shut down your Mac
2. Restart your Mac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: Since you 
   have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. can you login okay?)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your Mac as normal and see if you can login now

Comment: I tried that but it didn't asked me to enter the password twice and after I enter my password 1st time it goes till 100% and stays there.

Comment: Ok, so how long have you waited after the 100% ? It’s not uncommon for Safe mode to take 10+ minutes in some case, and about six months ago I came across a user who had to wait over 30 mins.

Comment: I tried that yesterday night and left it as it is and till morning it was stuck in 100%. Now, i just followed the instructions that you have given and waited for 20 mins still it was on 100%.