# Login screen stuck after entering password after BigSur update

Tags: macos, login-screen, big-sur

I updated to macOS BigSur, but after entering my password login is stuck. I tried couple approaches:

- starting in safe mode;
- reseting PRAM/NVRAM;
- reinstalling BigSur;
- also tried removing Csstore files described here [Macbook Pro stuck after I enter my password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305097/macbook-pro-stuck-after-i-enter-my-password;)
- I even did full disk erase and installed BigSur, then imported my data via migration assistant but still cannot log in to my account;

but it did not help. I have other accounts and I am able to login there. I also tried from those accounts to login with `su my_username` with terminal. I also changed the password that way, but all that did not help. I found the crash description in the logs of my user under `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/` and it seems that `accountsd` is crashing, bug type 309.

Is there a process to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact situation but migrated from something old to Monterey, but what worked for me was this other solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/412232/66547.

Specifically, say the migrated user was "Joe User":

1. Login with the original admin account (or create a new admin account)
2. Find the UID (user id) of the migrated user: `id joeuser` (say `502`)
3. Ensure the ownership of the migrated user's home folder: `sudo chown -R 502 /Users/joeuser/`
4. Delete the migrated user with the Users & Groups control panel. Choose the option to keep the user folder as it is. It will get renamed from `joeuser` to `joeuser (deleted)`
5. Go to the Users folder on your hard disk and re-rename `joeuser (deleted)` again to `joeuser`.
6. Ensure the ownership of the migrated user's home folder again (it might not have let you do all of it while an account existed): `sudo chown -R 502 /Users/joeuser/`
7. Add "Joe User" again with Users & Groups control panel. Make sure it gets the same user folder name (`joeuser`) and select the option to use the existing folder when you create it.

   - I did not set a password
8. Turn on "fast user switching", and switched to the `joeuser` account
9. It should show the account setup screens and asked you to connect to iCloud and set a new password

All credit goes to `Dirk` from the linked answer. Hope this is of help to future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Bummer. Before you try and reset the password, have you tried a safe mode start? (Power down, hold shift as the Mac starts)

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Here is the script to reset the password when it’s not working anymore.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860

Comment: I tried all of that. What I am doing now is manually copying data to new user :S

Comment: How did you get past the stuck login screen @nedo99 (or do you still have admin access to the Mac and only one account is “borked”)

Comment: I did not pass it. I had a 'admin' account and I could log in to that one, and in the end I made that one my account by copying data manually.

Comment: That’s a valid way to leave behind a broken user profile / keychain / preferences. Great solution @nedo99

Comment: Yes. Only downside is that now all settings (system and app) need to be done manually. Still a good lesson.

Comment: And those settings are highly sus now as to the cause of the issue @nedo99 (since it’s not the OS, the hardware, the apps or the data)