# After migration of a user to another Mac (Catalina to Big Sur, Intel to Apple Silicon) via Time Machine backup, user is stuck on login screen

Tags: time-machine, big-sur, migration

I setup my new MacBook Air M1 from scratch, just adding a new admin account. Then I connected my Time Machine backup disk from my older MacBook Air and used Migration Assistant to transfer my old admin account (which has a different name) to the new Mac.

This went successfully, but after restart I can not login with my migrated account. The password is accepted, but then the Mac is stuck at the login screen with a spinning process indicator and a notification about "Optimizing Your Mac". Nothing else seems to happen until I loose patience and restart.

Safe boot did not help. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login with the original admin account.
2. Delete the migrated user (say, "Joe User") with the Users & Groups control panel. Choose the option to keep the user folder as it is. It will get renamed from `joeuser` to `joeuser (deleted)`.
3. Go to the `Users` folder on your hard disk and re-rename `joeuser (deleted)` again to `joeuser`.
4. Add "Joe User" again with Users & Groups control panel. Make sure it gets the same user folder name (`joeuser`) and select the option to use the existing folder when you create it.

Comment: This did it for me! I tried question #305097 but that didn't work (didn't find any csstore files). I changed the password on the user but it was still stuck. I did not reset PRAM or anything, nor use safemode.

I noticed the user's folder had some other UIDs (506 when the user was 502) so I `sudo chown -R "$(whoami)" /Users/joeuser`, and then I followed these steps above. I did not set a password, then turned on "fast user switching", and switched to the `joeuser` account and voila: it went through account setup screens and asked me to connect to iCloud and set a new password.