# Login Screen Stuck after Big Sur update

Tags: macos, mac, big-sur, login, login-screen

I have a 2018 macbook pro which was running High Sierra. I upgraded it to Catalina and then transferred all my files from my old computer to my new one using Migration Assistant with a Time Machine backup. Then, I logged into my account and it worked.

However, I decided to upgrade my macbook to Big Sur. That went smoothly, but once I tried to login to my account, It just got stuck in an endless loading wheel.

Things I have tried:

1. Booting into Safe Mode
2. Reinstalling Big Sur
3. Deleting my user from system preferences and then using migration assistant to backup my files again

I have come to believe that Big Sur is not the problem, it is my account. I have an administrator account that works perfectly fine and I can easily login.

My account works with Catalina but not with Big Sur, why and how do I fix it?

Note: my previous computer (the one I migrated from) was running Catalina

Thanks!

Comment: Have your tried resetting the SMC and NVRAM/PRAM? You can also try booting in safe mode and see if logging in to you account is possible from there.

Comment: I haven't tried resetting that. I have already tried booting into safe mode, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact situation after migrating from something old to Monterey, but what worked for me was based on this other solution by `Dirk`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/412232/66547.

The full solution with my additional steps are here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436402/66547

Hope this is of help to future viewers.