# Stuck after entering login user password

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, crash

so, i am using macbook pro 13”2017with touchbar and using the latest version of macos high sierra just today when i tried to open my macbook, entering login password as normally i got into my mac and then it hangs after i tried to open chrome. So i hold power button until the macbook shutdown and powering on it again but this time after entering login password i got and black screen with only cursor that can be move.

so i hold power button again and shutdown the mac, and tried to login again but this time after entering password normally it will show loading bar, and just when the loading bar will finish (just leaving a little gap until finish) it stuck there, nothing happens...

so again i hold power button and shutdown it again and do everything the internet tell like safe boot, reset thing with (opt+cmd+r+p), reset other thing with (shift+crt+opt+powerbutton) and even doing macos reinstall but not erase the disk yet... also tried to check disk at recovery mode, nothing fixed it

now i am at recovery mode and using terminal looking for error log or crash log and i find that at /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports there is alot of crash report with name:  xartstorageremoted_2018-05-29-130152_Tonys-Macbook-Pro.crash file.

after searching again xartstorageremoted is something that have to do with touchbar and camera... but can’t find anything regarding creating crash.

so maybe there is some expert here that can help me? Since in my city there is no apple store or any authorized service provider for apple device.

**update**
so I found out the problem is because my current user account is somewhat broken/corrupted still don't sure yet but after creating a new account by deleting .applesetupdone files then I finally can get into the Mac.... but because this is new account then the entire application setting and others is also different... so how do I migrate those things?

Comment: Do you have enough free space?

Comment: yes, there is alot of space left

Comment: Just a guess: have you tried to clear all information from the Secure Enclave in the Touch Bar?  See number 6 https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065 . In Recovery: `xartutil --erase-all`

Comment: Nope not working at all still stuck at login bar

Comment: I looks indeed like your user account is broken. Did you check this comment? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305097/macbook-pro-stuck-after-i-enter-my-password/327099#327099 It did fix it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem is my user account is broken and in the end i need just to create a new user account but because there is so much to taken care of i end up doing erase all and reinstall mac...

and now everything is works just fine.