# Big Sur - Logging in after sleep sometimes doesn't work

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-lock, login-screen, big-sur

I have a MacBook Pro 2018 and after upgrading from High Sierra to BigSur, I sometines can't log in after putting my Mac to sleep with <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>.

**I don't always have the issue and can't exactly reproduce it**, but sometimes, after locking my Mac with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, when I enter my password and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the login screen freezes. I can move the mouse, can interact with the Touch Bar (for example, play music).

Does someone have any idea how this issue could be fixed without a fresh install?

Comment: I think that is something with authorization service, etc..Because I wanted to upgrade VMWare Fusion and the wizard asked me for Password and after that, the APP was stalled

Comment: I have something very similar and also suspect it is connected to authorization issues. I myslef don't use control keys to make the mac sleep, but for the last (approx) six months, after  automatic sleeps I experience a 30% chance that on wake I will see the log in screen (except the password box) and can control music, volume, see notifications (but not interact with them), but get an eternal spinning wait cursor and am never shown the password box.

Comment: The reason I think there is a connection with authorization is that the onky other wierd thing that the computer does concern s changing passwords on sites where keychain access has stored things.  There I frequently (though not always) get a 20 second spinning wait while the machine does trivial operations (like populating an old password) during prior to an attempt at a password change. This has not happened to me prior to the last few months, and is definitely not right. Ties in with the login issue to, as that is to do with passwords.

Answer (score 2):

I am also having this issue. So far it looks like giving it more time to “wake” before entering password helps a bit for me.
And there are already other people seeing the same problem with old macOS releases, so I guess Apple will fix it.  see here: [Macbook Pro stuck after I enter my password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305097/macbook-pro-stuck-after-i-enter-my-password/328390#328390)

Comment: I tried to wait to wake up approximately 3 hours without any results...

Comment: I've noticed, that if use only fingerprint sensor, the problem disapears...will test a bit more

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue. Mine is mac pro m1 and this error causing no backlight on the touch bar. All I can do is wait for the password screen to show up and turn off my device. But sometimes this causing my device to restart and shows error reports (kernel panic). Idk why this happens, probably because big sur bugs.

Answer (score 0):

So while I have this issue still, I can share my findings on what I've been doing to "fix it" on my model.

I've been running into two issues:

- the exact same issue when returning from sleep with the same shortcut, where I get a frozen login screen;
- I can actually log into my computer - or what seems like I logged in since I see my windows - and move my mouse, etc., But can't really interact with anything (get the "error" sound);

Now, my model is a fingerprint (TouchID) enabled Macbook. What I have noticed is that if I simply "re-authenticate" myself on the fingerprint sensor, I will get everything unblocked. Just rest your finger on the sensor again. This works about 99% of the time (I think it may have failed once). Hopefully this helps someone else.